# tabular not move on the next page?

Tags: tables, formatting

I am new with latex and I use texmaker for documentation . I begin `tabular` tag but the problem is all the date in `tabular` tag is embed on the current page . It is not moving automatically on the next page. It should  break automatically and move to the next page.The code here:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{9cm}|}
\hline
Term &  Definition [3ex]
\hline
...
having ten more row available in it
...
...
\end{tabular}
```

Table having ten rows and two column squeeze in a same page.Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use the `longtable` package to allow a table to span multiple pages.

Comment: tabulars are not breakable. longtable should solve it.